# how to access the view child of plugin inside modal to get instance of that plugin?

Tags: angular, cropperjs

In angular 7 im using ngx-cropperjs plugin to crop the images,
But i have placed my plug in directive inside my modal body , like

```
<ng-template #template>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Create Listing</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ngx-cropperjs #angularCropper [cropperOptions]="configCrop" [imageUrl]="imageUrl" (export)="resultImageFun($event)"></ngx-cropperjs>
        <button (click)="CropMe()">CropMe</button>
            <br>
        <img [src]="resultResult" />
    </div>
```

in my ts, im opening the modal using following method

```
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.modalConfig);
              }
```

for the cropper plugin i have a viewchild like

```
@ViewChild('angularCropper') public angularCropper: NgxCropperjsComponent;
```

if the ngx-cropper is out side the modal, i will get instance in  console.log directly

```
 console.log("angularCropper", this.angularCropper)
```

but as the plugin is inside modal im getting undefined, how can i access the instance of the plugin now?

Comment: Can you create s small example on stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-container to access inner view-child.

```
<ng-template #template>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <angular-cropper #angularCropper [cropperOptions]="config" [imageUrl]="imageUrl"></angular-cropper>
        <img [src]="imgUrl"/>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
```

I have created demo with that.
Please have a look.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/cropper-js-demo